# Need Java Swing HTML canvas with support for integrated swing controls

Tags: java, html, swing

I would like to create an application in swing in the style of web 2.0 but have the power and functionality of a thick client. I know substance and some other look and feels help with this some, but I was wondering if there is a way I can actually use some kind of html panel / canvas to create the content in html, embedding swing controls in the rendering so as to still use listeners and get the functionality.

Anybody know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for some kind of html script that inherits from the swing class?